# datareader fails but does not raise exception c#

Tags: c#, mysql, exception, datareader

I am new to C# and I find some of the exception handling, or lack there of to be puzzling.  I am trying to catch these exceptions but they are not caught I don't understand why.    The code will cak after the exception and everything after the exception will be ignored, the next line executed will be a paint event for the form.

Obviously I can fix this example easily but I want to know why the exception is not raised.   I have seen this quite a bit.

Here is an example:

```
public DataTable GetTaskDescription( string EstmateNameGuid)
    {
        string strJobNumName = null;

        MySqlCommand cmd = null;
        MySqlDataReader dr = null;
        MySqlConnection myconnection = new MySqlConnection(clsGlobeVar.localDB);
        myconnection.Open();
        DataTable table1 = new DataTable("EstGuids");

        string select = GetTaskDescription_SQLCreate();
        try
        {

            cmd = new MySqlCommand(select, myconnection);
            GetTaskDescription_ParameterFill(ref  cmd, clsGlobeVar.ClientGuid, EstmateNameGuid);

            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.HasRows)
            {                 
                table1.Columns.Add("Estimate_Guid");
                table1.Columns.Add("Estimate_Description");
                table1.Columns.Add("Estimate_Date");
                table1.Columns.Add("Active");
                string [] field = new string[5] ;

                while (dr.Read())
                {  
                    // going to read field in the row.
                    field[0] =  dr.SafeGetString(0);
                    field[1] =  dr.SafeGetString(1);
                    field[2] =  dr.SafeGetString(2);
                    field[3] =  dr.SafeGetString(3);
                      // this field does not exist but I tried to read it
                     // this should fail and raise an exception  
                     // it does fail but does not raise the exception
                    field[4] =  dr.SafeGetString(4);
                }
    }

   // this catch is ignored
catch (MySqlException ex)  
     {  some code }

// the finally block executes okay
finally  { some clean up}
// and this return statement is ignored and the code in the caller does not execute
return table1
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Maybe you aren't throwing a mysqlexception, try catch the heretic exception and see what error is thrown

Comment: You were right.  I was not throwing a mysqlexception even though I was only using mysql objects.   Lots to learn here.     Thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handling exceptions in this way is generally not recommended, as you can never be sure what exceptions your nested code actually throws.
You should at least add a handler for unexpected ones:

```
catch (MySqlException ex)  
 {  some code }
catch (Exception ex)
{
   //Unexpected exception thrown...
}
```

Comment: That did it.    I guess in general I am not catching the right exceptions.   .  More to learn.... Thanks for the help.

Comment: There is a good article about exception handling you might want to read. Its by Joel Spolsky, one of the founders of stackoverflow: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2003/10/13.html

Comment: Joel is clearly not a fan.   Not a real fan here either.   The part I don't like is how an uncaught exception sends you to outer space and you have no idea how you got there.   4 function/method calls deep and something goes wrong and boom, your painting the screen.   8(...  and no idea how you got there.  A huge goto.  How do you avoid it though?

Comment: I think the basic point is, that you should always catch errors as soon as possible and then provide an appropriate handling when you still can. A backup catch() for the unexpected exception here or there should also be there - just don't rely on them.